# preg_replace inside of preg_match_all problems

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I'm trying to find some certain blocks in my data file and replace something inside of them. After that put the whole thing (with replaced data) into a new file. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.ext', true);

//find certain pattern blocks first
preg_match_all('/regexp/su', $content, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
  //replace data inside of those blocks
  preg_replace('/regexp2/su', 'replacement', $match);
}

file_put_contents('new_file.ext', return_whole_thing?);
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to return_whole_thing. Basically, file.ext and new_file.ext are almost the same except of the replaced data.
Any suggestion what should be on place of `return_whole_thing`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to strengthen your regular expression to find a subpattern within the original pattern. That way you can just call preg_replace() and be done with it.

```
$new_file_contents = preg_replace('/regular(Exp)/', 'replacement', $content);
```

This can be done with "( )" within the regular expression. A quick google search for "regular expression subpatterns" resulted in [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression+subpatterns&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the preg_replace; because you've already got the matches you can just use a normal str_replace like so:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.ext', true);

//find certain pattern blocks first
preg_match_all('/regexp/su', $content, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
  //replace data inside of those blocks
  $content = str_replace( $match, 'replacement', $content)
}

file_put_contents('new_file.ext', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. Could you perhaps post an example of:

- file.ext, the original file
- the regex you want to use and what you want to replace matches with
- new_file.ext, your desired output

If you just want to read `file.ext`, replace a regex match, and store the result in `new_file.ext`, all your need is:

```
$content = file_get_contents('file.ext');
$content = preg_replace('/match/', 'replacement', $content);
file_put_contents('new_file.ext', $content);
```